# Unable to import pexpect "windows only" methods

Tags: python, pexpect, winpexpect

I have recently installed the pexpect 4.0 module, as it will be quite useful for the program I am creating. I do have windows, so I looked specifically at the exceptions for pexpect, knowing that the normal spawn and run methods aren't available to me. But, I cant get the "windows methods" that the module is supposed to show windows users, which are:

pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn, and pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get these methods? I am running on windows 10, python 3.4.

Side note: I am currently working on trying to get winpexpect to import the spawn module from pexpect, but I am also failing at that as well.

Comment: what do you mean by "cant get the windows methods"?  What exactly are you doing, seeing?  error messages would be useful too.

Comment: Sorry, I am not receiving any error messages. When I tab to auto complete, I see:

`pexpect.EOF, pexpect.ExceptionPexpect, pexpect.Expecter,pexpect.PY3, pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.exceptions, pexpect.expect, pexpect.is_executable_file, pexpect.searcher_re, pexpect.searcher_string, pexpect.split_command_line, pexpect.sys, pexpect.utils, pexpect.which`


The windows methods are the methods listed above, because pexpect uses pty, which windows doesn't support. So these methods were supposed to be a work around.

Comment: edit: @ivan7707 I forgot to tag you in the last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
from pexpect import popen_spawn, fdpexpect
```

Then you can do the rest of what you needed.

edit:  this is the reason you did not see it, in the __init__.py notice this:

```
__all__ = ['ExceptionPexpect', 'EOF', 'TIMEOUT', 'spawn', 'spawnu', 'run','runu', 'which', 'split_command_line', '__version__', '__revision__']
```

Comment: If I edit that line to include those modules, would it show it?

Comment: I answered your question in my response which works(that you should mark as such).  So this is a different question that you should look to the documents for.  That said, you can add from pexpect import popen_spawn, fdpexpect and the names to the \__all__ in quotes they will show up.  I wouldn't do that though, since the package author set it up this way.